# Scons - How to stop cleaning dependent targets/files on cleaning final target?

Tags: scons

I have two targets A and B.
B depends on A, therefore if we build B, also A is built.
now if B is cleaned, A is cleaned as well.
A is a collection of .obj-files and the resulting library  .
request: When cleaning B, nothing of target A is touched/removed
Here is my code:

```
    {env = Environment()
     src1 = ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c']
     obj1 = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in src1 ]
     lib = env.Library('tridip', obj1)
     Alias('library', lib)
     src2 = ['tridip3.c']
     obj2 = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in src2 ]
     exe = Program(obj2, LIBS=lib, LIBPATH='.')
     Alias('exe', exe)
}
```

Target A is tridip.lib tridip.obj tridip1.obj tridip2.obj
Target B is :tridip3.exe /LIBPATH:. tridip.lib tridip3.obj

Request: How do I stop cleaning target A on cleaning target B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [NoClean](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0/HTML/scons-user/x3145.html) function.  Here is how to update your SConstruct.

```
env = Environment()
src1 = ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c']
obj1 = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in src1 ]
lib = env.Library('tridip', obj1)
if 'library' not in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
    env.NoClean([obj1, lib])
Alias('library', lib)
src2 = ['tridip3.c']
obj2 = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in src2 ]
exe = Program(obj2, LIBS=lib, LIBPATH='.')
Alias('exe', exe)
```

Which when run produces the following...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> tree
.
├── SConstruct
├── tridip1.c
├── tridip1.h
├── tridip2.c
├── tridip2.h
├── tridip3.c
├── tridip.c
└── tridip.h

0 directories, 8 files

>> scons library
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o tridip.o -c tridip.c
gcc -o tridip1.o -c tridip1.c
gcc -o tridip2.o -c tridip2.c
ar rc libtridip.a tridip.o tridip1.o tridip2.o
ranlib libtridip.a
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── libtridip.a
├── SConstruct
├── tridip1.c
├── tridip1.h
├── tridip1.o
├── tridip2.c
├── tridip2.h
├── tridip2.o
├── tridip3.c
├── tridip.c
├── tridip.h
└── tridip.o

0 directories, 12 files

>> scons library -c
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Cleaning targets ...
Removed tridip.o
Removed tridip1.o
Removed tridip2.o
Removed libtridip.a
scons: done cleaning targets.

>> tree
.
├── SConstruct
├── tridip1.c
├── tridip1.h
├── tridip2.c
├── tridip2.h
├── tridip3.c
├── tridip.c
└── tridip.h

0 directories, 8 files

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o tridip.o -c tridip.c
gcc -o tridip1.o -c tridip1.c
gcc -o tridip2.o -c tridip2.c
ar rc libtridip.a tridip.o tridip1.o tridip2.o
ranlib libtridip.a
gcc -o tridip3.o -c tridip3.c
gcc -o tridip3 tridip3.o -L. libtridip.a
scons: done building targets.

>> scons -c
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Cleaning targets ...
Removed tridip3.o
Removed tridip3
scons: done cleaning targets.

>> tree
.
├── libtridip.a
├── SConstruct
├── tridip1.c
├── tridip1.h
├── tridip1.o
├── tridip2.c
├── tridip2.h
├── tridip2.o
├── tridip3.c
├── tridip.c
├── tridip.h
└── tridip.o

0 directories, 12 files
```

Comment: Thanks! this is useful. I notice, if I build target A and clean same target A, it is not cleaned. Request : if I build target A and clean same target A, it should be cleaned whereas, if I build target B and clean same target B then target A should not be cleaned. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: @TridipBhagawati I modified the answer to address your expanded question.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. I wonder, can we use the NoClean() like env.NoClean('exe ', [obj1, lib]) or any other option.

Comment: @TridipBhagawati I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your last comment.  env.NoClean() just takes a list of all the targets you do not want to have cleaned.  If you want to include the exe in that list just make it env.NoClean([exe, obj1, lib])

Comment: Well, you have added an "if" condition - if 'library' not in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
    env.NoClean([obj1, lib])
I would like to know, does NoClean() supports - NoClean('exe', [obj1, lib]), which means when I clean target 'exe' I stop cleaning obj1 and lib. Thanks!